# How to right align select NavBar items to the right using Flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, navbar

I am looking to create push items to the right using Flexbox.

Desired NavBar output: **About Store.............Right Right**

I have tried selecting #right and using margin-left:auto but the right is not pushing

```
This is currently my HTML code
<nav>
  <div class="navbarcontainer">
    <ul> 
      <li id="left"><a href="#"></a>About</li>
      <li id="left"><a href="#"></a>Store</li>
      <li id="right"><a href="#"></a>Right</li>
      <li id="right"><a href="#"></a>Right</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </nav>
```

This is my CSS code

```
.navbarcontainer {
  display:flex;
  border: 1px solid #2d2d2d; 

}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 4px ;
  font: black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: only a small mistake, just use your display: flex on ul and not on its parent

Comment: "About Store" - left and "Right Right" - right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

only a small mistake, just use your display: flex on ul and not on its parent, and yes, don't use an ID on 2 elements,
**ID's are meant to be UNIQUE.**

```css
    .navbarcontainer {

      border: 1px solid #2d2d2d; 

    }
    .navbarcontainer ul {
      display:flex;
      padding-left: 0;
    }
    li {
      list-style-type: none;
      font-size: 14px;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 4px ;
      font: black;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    #right {
    margin-left: auto;
    }
```

```html
    <nav>
      <div class="navbarcontainer">
        <ul> 
          <li id="left"><a href="#"></a>About</li>
          <li id=""><a href="#"></a>Store</li>
          <li id="right"><a href="#"></a>Right</li>
          <li id=""><a href="#"></a>Right</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `justify-content: space-between` to align item in corner of `div`

```css
.nav-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #2d2d2d;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 4px;
  font: black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <ul class="leftNav">
      <li id="left"><a href="#"></a>About</li>
      <li id="left"><a href="#"></a>Store</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="rightNav">
      <li id="right"><a href="#"></a>Right</li>
      <li id="right"><a href="#"></a>Right</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of the class navbarcontainer, you have to use flex display with

```css
.navbarcontainer {
  display:flex;
  border: 1px solid #2d2d2d; 
width:100vw
}
ul{
display:flex;
width:100%;
justify-content:space-between
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 4px ;
  font: black;
}
.left{
display:flex}
.right{
display:flex}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="navbarcontainer">
    <ul> 
    <div class="left">
      <li ><a href="#"></a>About</li>
      <li ><a href="#"></a>Store</li>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
      <li  ><a href="#"></a>Right</li>
      <li><a href="#"></a>Right</li>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </nav>
```